# Errors in a Swift 3 Drawing Application

Tags: swift3, drawing, xcode8

I am making a drawing application in Swift 3 using Xcode 8. I tried to follow a tutorial, but can't seem to find the answer to these errors in the comments section of that site.

Here are the two sets of errors that I keep getting:

[image: This is the first set of errors that I get]

[image: this is the second set of errors that I am getting]

```
context?.setLineCap(kCALineCapRound)
context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
context?.setBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
    mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: opacity)
mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to trouble shoot these two errors that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you find something wrong in your code, please check the [official API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference).

[setLineCap(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454326-setlinecap)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func setLineCap(_ cap: CGLineCap)
> ```

[CGLineCap](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cglinecap)

> **Enumeration**
>
> #### CGLineCap

You need to pass a `CGLineCap` value to `setLineCap(_:)` method, and in Swift 3 it's enum, so you need to pass an enum case.

This line:

```
context?.setLineCap(kCALineCapRound)
```

should be something like this:

```
context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
```

or simply like this:

```
context?.setLineCap(.round)
```

(By the way `kCALineCapRound` is not a valid constant for `setLineCap`  -- `CGContextSetLineCap` even in former Swift and Objective-C. It should be [`kCGLineCapRound`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cglinecap/kcglinecapround?language=objc))

---

Again...

[setBlendMode(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455994-setblendmode)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func setBlendMode(_ mode: CGBlendMode)
> ```

[CGBlendMode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgblendmode)

> **Enumeration**
>
> #### CGBlendMode

Change this line:

```
context?.setBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal)
```

to this:

```
context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
```

or this:

```
context?.setBlendMode(.normal)
```

Similar changes (and some simple fixes) are needed for your *second set of errors*.

---

You'd better take some time to find a good Swift 3 tutorial, or else you may spend more time to learn how to migrate codes from Swift 2 to Swift 3, than to make an application in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am a first time student learning to code and finding the approriate tutorials is hard as well as figuring out the shift from swift 2 to 3.  The feedback helped

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to the tutorial that you mention, I have found a Swift 3 update at this link: https://github.com/dragosholban/DrawPad.

Based on that project, the two blocks of code that you need to fix would become:

```
context?.setLineCap(.round)
context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
context?.setBlendMode(.normal)
```

and

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
mainImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: opacity)
mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I know it's maybe late, but I hope this can help other people too, 'cause I was trying to fix those errors myself but got stuck due to some erroneous tips from Xcode, until I found the github project in the link.

Comment: For further information, you can find my code on github in here: https://github.com/gtempesta/DrawPad